# Is it possible to define a ColdFusion's struct member value as a function using its other members?

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-10

Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
<cfset Accounts = {
    "Number Sold" = { value =  5000  } 
    ,"Total Sales" = { value =  25000  }
    ,"Avg. Sale Price" = { value = this["Number Sold"] / this["Total Sales"] }
} >
```

Obviously, this isn't valid syntax for ColdFusion. But is there any way to define a struct's key/value pair as having a value of some mathematical function involving the other members?

Comment: Are you able to assign the values to variables before the struct? E.g.  `<cfset variables.numberSold = 5000>` and `<cfset variables.totalSales = 25000>`. You could then do `value =  variables.numberSold / variables.totalSales`

Comment: That's actually pretty much what I ended up doing, but I'm still curious if this is possible at all.

Comment: Interesting idea. To do it dynamically, you'd need a way to reference the parent container, like you can within a component by using `variables` or `this`. AFAIK, that isn't possible with a structure. Though I'd love to be proven wrong :-)

Comment: Not exactly what you were looking for, but here is the closest I could get. https://gist.github.com/boyzoid/b712a31232ad8f033b503a745720d57c

Tested in Lucee only.